# The difference between our sample estimate and the true population value is known as:

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

The difference between our sample estimate and the true population value is known as:

A. Mean Value

B. Standard Deviation

C. Standard Error

D. Variance

With explanation please

Answer (score 2):

None of your four options describes the difference between a single sample statistic and the population parameter. Population parameters are typically unknown (that is why we draw samples to calculate estimates and draw inferences) and so it doesn't make sense to think about the difference between a single sample statistic and an unknown quantity. Instead, perhaps you are thinking about the amount of uncertainty in a sample statistic due to sampling? In that case, the standard error is the closest answer - this is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of your statistic. As your sample size increases, this value decreases.

Can you provide some more information about what you are trying to understand?

Comment: danCloney is right. I'd add that if the sample estimate is, say, the sample mean (rather than the median or any other sample credible estimate), then the difference between the sample mean and the population mean is $z ~se = z~\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ when the variance is known or $t~se= t~s/\sqrt{n}$ when the variance has to be estimated from the data.

Answer (score -1):

Given

- true value is $\theta$
- sample estimate is $\hat \theta$

then

- Variance, $ \sigma^2 = \mathbb E[ (\hat \theta - \theta)^2 ] $
- Standard Deviation, $\sigma = \sqrt(\text{Variance}) $

Accordingly, an estimate of the difference might be B. Standard Deviation

Comment: How does this relate to the  definition of variance given e.g. in https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/variance/info?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I apologize for the hasty Answer. I've added the previously omitted use of Expectation($\mathbb E$)